# Physics golf: inclined shooting

Tags: code-golf, math, physics

An [angry bird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angry_birds) is shot at an angle \$β\$ to the horizontal at a speed \$u\$. The ground is steep, inclined at an angle \$α\$. Find the horizontal distance \$q\$ that the bird traveled before it hit the ground.

[image: diagram showing an inclined plane at angle α and an angry bird being fired at angle β at speed u]

Make a function \$f(α, β, u)\$ that returns the length \$q\$: the horizontal distance that the bird traveled before it hit the ground.

Constraints and notes:

- \$-90° < α < 90°\$.
- \$0° < β < 180°\$.
- \$α < β\$.
- \$0 \le u < 10^9\$.
- Assume acceleration due to gravity \$g = 10\$.
- You may use radians instead of degrees for \$α\$, \$β\$.
- Dimensions of \$u\$ are irrelevant as long as they are consistent with \$g\$ and \$q\$.
- No air resistance or anything too fancy.

Shortest code wins.

See the Wikipedia article on [projectile motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion) for some equations.

Samples:

```
f(0, 45, 10) = 10
f(0, 90, 100) = 0
f(26.565, 45, 10) = 5
f(26.565, 135, 10) = 15
```

Comment: As I saw some confusion about the formula, here it is for others to use it: `q = ABS[1/5 u^2 Cos[β] Sec[α] Sin[β - α]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Java

Works for radians only

```java
double q(double a, double b, double u){
          return (Math.abs(((-Math.tan(a)+(Math.tan(b)))*(u*u)*(0.2*(Math.cos(b)*Math.cos(b))))));
      }
```

Golfed Version (Thanks to Peter)

```java
double z=u*Math.cos(b);return(Math.tan(b)-Math.tan(a))*z*z/5;
```

Maths Used:

$$
q = ut\cos \beta \\
q\tan \alpha = ut\sin \beta - 0.5 \times 10 t^2 \\
- \tan \alpha + \tan \beta  = 5\frac q {u^2} \sec^2 \beta \\
q = \frac {(\tan \beta - \tan \alpha)u^2} {5\sec^2 \beta }
$$

Comment: There is something wrong with this... I just cant figure out correctly, can some1 help?

Comment: This formula is not correct. Please see comment at gnibbler's post

Comment: So yet, we dont have any perfect solution :)

Comment: updated the formula...  fire some testcases now please

Comment: You can save a few chars - Math.abs is unnecessary, -x+y is shorter as y-x, *0.2 is shorter as /5, and you have unnecessary brackets. OTOH you're missing the return type of the method.

Comment: Thanks for return type :)   Was just curious on getting the answer than golfing..I would let this be as it is.. for readability purpose!

Comment: @Aman: I can't test it right now but it seems correct. There are some test cases in the problem description that you may try.

Comment: The testcases given seems to work fine (with small difference in answer, perhaps because of radians and PIs)

Comment: @Aman, IMO it's much more readable as `return (Math.tan(b)-Math.tan(a))*u*u*Math.cos(b)*Math.cos(b)/10;` The golfed version would be `double z=u*Math.cos(b);return(Math.tan(b)-Math.tan(a))*z*z/10;` (two chars shorter...)

Comment: lol, Come On Peter, anyway Java would loose a golfing compeition, But I like your idea, I will edit my post!

Comment: @Aman, oops, that should be /5, not /10. I blame a lack of coffee ;) But I'm serious about finding it more readable with fewer parentheses: when they're nested five or six deep it takes effort to pair them up.

Comment: [:p] edited....

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell (<s>37</s> 35)

Based on Aman's solution:

```
q a b u=(tan a+tan b)*u*u*cos b^2/5
```

I think, this problem isn't real code-golf, as it is more implementing a formula than really doing some algorithm.

Comment: Maybe you are right, since the formula is already too short.

Comment: Would something like `/5` or `/5.` work?

Comment: This formula is not correct. Please see comment at gnibbler's post.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3 - 65 chars

```py
from math import*
f=lambda α,β,u:(tan(α)+tan(β))*u*u*.2*cos(β)**2
```

Comment: That's not quite correct. 1) f should always be positive and 2) for α > 0 it returns a larger value than for a=0, which is not possible.

Comment: Ah well, I copied FUZxxl's formula :/